# How do I make a Vaadin theme that extends Valo?

Tags: sass, themes, vaadin, vaadin7

I need to slightly tweak the Valo theme for our Vaadin project.  When I try to follow the vaadin documentation [here](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/themes.valo.html) I see this...

[image]

Essentially the .scss file for my new custom theme cannot find "valo" which makes sense, I never added a bunch of .scss files that are the "valo" source.  Am I missing a step?  Do I need to download the Valo sources and dump them into my java project?  Do I need to add a maven dependency?

Comment: Have you tried if it works even the editor is complaining. I have the same error in IntelliJ and it works.

Comment: intellij does not look into other resources/jars for sass includes.  it is not aware of the way, the sass compiler of vaadin works.  it deals you the errors you would get with the regular filesystem based approach of the ruby one. so unless your app really throws some errors (please add them to the question), ignore this - it's the same for all of us. and make sure you have `com.vaadin:vaadin-themes` deps loaded nontheless.

Answer (score 1):

Do you include the file anywhere. Because if you don't you would need use ".ethortheme" instead of "@mixin ethortheme". @mixin is used when you want to @include the block somewhere.

There is also a description in the vaadin documentation how to extend the valo theme.

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/themes.valo.html#themes.valo.use